# What is the most effective way of summing the values from multiple columns and creating a new column of the total value in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, subquery, coalesce

This is the code I attempted to create the view and add the multiple distance columns to obtain the total distance:

```
CREATE
OR ALTER VIEW map_view AS
SELECT     lookup.UniqueID
           lookup.road1,
           lookup.pavement1,
           lookup.distance1,
           lookup.remarks1,
           lookup.SurveyResult1,
           lookup.road2,
           lookup.pavement2,
           lookup.distance2,
           lookup.remarks2,
           lookup.SurveyResult2,
           lookup.road3,
           lookup.pavement3,
           lookup.distance3,
           lookup.remarks3,
           lookup.SurveyResult3,
           lookup.road4,
           lookup.pavement4,
           lookup.distance4,
           lookup.remarks4,
           lookup.SurveyResult4,
           lookup.road5,
           lookup.pavement5,
           lookup.distance5,
           lookup.remarks5,
           lookup.SurveyResult5,
           lookup.road6,
           lookup.pavement6,
           lookup.distance6,
           SUM(ISNULL(lookup.distance1,0) + ISNULL(lookup.distance2,0) + ISNULL(lookup.distance3,0)
           + ISNULL(lookup.distance4,0) + ISNULL(lookup.distance5,0)) AS TotalDistance
FROM 

lookup
```

The **TotalDistance** (last line in select statement) is an aggregation of the values in the distance (distance1, distance2 etc) columns. Nulls are present in the distance columns that is why I used ISNULL. What method achieves the aggregation and has the optimal performance.

Comment: You *really* need to fix your design here. You're breaking the most basic of principles of normalisation here; [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Fix the design, and you'll have a much easier time, in my opinion. If you fix your design, you can easily then just use `SUM`.

Comment: Agreed that normalisation principles are not being adhered to, but fixing the design of the  underlying tables and the final view is not possible and beyond the scope. It's a replication of a transformation previously done in python, but all in SQL.

Comment: *"but fixing the design is not possible and beyond the scope"* Yet you want a performant solution; those 2 statement basically conflict.

Comment: What are you really asking? The code you've shown would result in an error, because you aren't grouping. Sounds like you can just remove the `SUM` and add those columns together for each row.